# C programming - Sodoku solution (backtracking)

Tags: c, recursion, backtracking

the Question is: to get from the user sodoku board and if there is a solution to print it, if not to print no solution!
the solution of the soduko: two identical numbers mmust not appear on the same line;
two identical numbers must not appear in the same colum.
I worte a program that works perfectly when I put the soduko board and the size (global parametes-as shown un my code) but when I tried to receive from the user it took so much time to run the solution and sometimes it didn't retun anything. I would like to understand why?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5


int matrix[5][5] = {
    {4,2,0,0,5},
    {2,0,0,1,3},
    {5,0,1,2,0},
    {0,0,3,0,2},
    {0,0,0,0,0},
};


void print_sudoku()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int number_unassigned(int *row, int *col)
{
    int num_unassign = 0;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] == 0)
            {
                *row = i;
                *col = j;
                num_unassign = 1;
                return num_unassign;
            }
        }
    }
    return num_unassign;
}


int is_safe(int n, int r, int c)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(matrix[r][i] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(matrix[i][c] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


int solve_sudoku()
{
    int row;
    int col;
 
    if(number_unassigned(&row, &col) == 0)
        return 1;

    int i;

    for(i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)
    {
  
        if(is_safe(i, row, col))
        {
            matrix[row][col] = i;

            if(solve_sudoku())
                return 1;

            matrix[row][col]=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    if (solve_sudoku())
        print_sudoku();
    else
        printf("No solution!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is whe code that I used to ask the user to enter a sodoku board:

```
int** ReadSoduko(int n) {
    int** matrix = (int**) malloc((sizeof(int*)) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    }
    printf("\nEnter your soduko board:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          printf("Enter row [%d]: ", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: The board has numbers from 1 to 9, but the solver only checks numbers from 1 to 5: `for(i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)`. There might not be a solution using 1 thru 5, so the solver needs to check every possibility. With 12 empty spaces, it would take 5^12 = 244e6 attempts to determine that there's no solution. If the user makes a larger board with more empty spaces, it could take a lot longer.

Comment: sorry I correctred the matrix, in this question they asked to assume that the input is correct. the code works for  me. my problem is when I tried to put into it possiblity for the user to insert his sodoku board I had problems with running it.

Comment: the program works really good ( excutive time 0.047 seconds), as I said I don't have problem with the program itself but when i replace the matrix with the function ReadSodoku then I have problems running it.

Comment: Ok, then show that code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is related to one thing: `#define SIZE` that you are probably forgetting to update when reading dynamically. Since you use `SIZE` in your loops, if that is not the real size of your matrix, then it probably won't work. I've changed 2 lines and added 3 other (the lines with comments at the end). Try it now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SIZE; //changed here

int** matrix; //changed here

void print_sudoku()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int number_unassigned(int* row, int* col)
{
    int num_unassign = 0;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
            {
                *row = i;
                *col = j;
                num_unassign = 1;
                return num_unassign;
            }
        }
    }
    return num_unassign;
}


int is_safe(int n, int r, int c)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[r][i] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][c] == n)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


int solve_sudoku()
{
    int row;
    int col;

    if (number_unassigned(&row, &col) == 0)
        return 1;

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {

        if (is_safe(i, row, col))
        {
            matrix[row][col] = i;

            if (solve_sudoku())
                return 1;

            matrix[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int** ReadSoduko(int n) {
    int** matrix = (int**)malloc((sizeof(int*)) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    }
    printf("\nEnter your soduko board:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("Enter row [%d]: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Size of matrix: "); //added this
    scanf("%d", &SIZE); //added this
    matrix = ReadSoduko(SIZE); //added this
    if (solve_sudoku())
        print_sudoku();
    else
        printf("No solution!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And don't forget that the matrix that you have declared statically doesn't have a solution! I have tested the same matrix, just `replacing the 2 in first line by a 0` and it worked here.

Comment: thank you, now it worked. but the  excutive time now is big, they asked us to think of a code that does it in few second. i need to think of a way to improve it

Comment: does it have to be dynmically allocated? You are probably losing speed due to cache miss. Maybe you could allocate a bigger matrix statically and use just the amount you need. Or you could allocate an array of size N * N.

Comment: the code works ok with every sodoku board I gave but with 9*9 sodoku with no solution it doesn't work.. do you have any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? What dos want it to do ano whats is It doing instead? Which values dos tou teu?